# LINQ Filter and Convert C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Would like to both filter and convert a List.  I can filter but cannot figure out how to convert.  PROBLEM, the return statement returns a List of FieldDef.  How do I get a List of the FieldDefsEnum1 from fieldsDefs?  Thanks in advance.

```
    FieldDefEnum1 : FieldDef 

    List<FileDef> fieldDefs

    public List<FieldDefEnum1> FieldDefsEnum1
    {
        get
        {
            return FieldDefs.Where(fd => fd.GetType() == typeof(FieldDefEnum1)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added a question on Filter and Convert Part 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) instead:

```
return FieldDefs.OfType<FieldDefEnum1>().ToList();
```

Comment: Bah, you were faster, +1 to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
FieldDefs.OfType<FieldDefEnum1>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert arbitrarily ("map") between values, use [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758#SelectSimple1).

[`OfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336748#OfType) probably does the filtering and converting you need more succintly - although it will include subclasses of the given type, not just instances of that specific type.